# MacBook Pro 1,1 Not Detecting Grub?

Tags: grub2, uefi, macbook-pro, 14.10

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my MacBookPro 1,1.

The installation went okay, however GRUB does not work. It's not even detected.

I can not `bless` the Linux disc due to a wiping of OSX. I do not have an install DVD.

I read that this is due to OSX-EFI running on i386, but I have no idea on how it can be installed.